# if a letter is found in word1 and is in word2, delete letter from word2

Tags: python

In my program that I am writing in Python, I am trying to say:

if a letter is found in word 1 and is in word2:

delete the letter from word2

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(word1)):
    if word1[i] in word2:
       del word1[i] in word2
```

When I did this, a syntax error came from the word **in** in the very last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`del`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) is only used to remove names (variables) in Python.

If you want to remove individual characters in a string, you should use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). Also note that instead of iterating over indexes, you can just iterate over the characters of the string:

```
for char in word1:
    if char in word2:
        word2 = word2.replace(char, '')
```

Of course, `replace` won’t actually replace anything if it can’t find a match, so you can just remove the `if`:

```
for char in word1:
    word2 = word2.replace(char, '')
```

And finally, `word1` may contain characters more than once, in which case you would try to remove single characters multiple times. So instead, you can just iterate over the *unique* characters of `word1`:

```
for char in set(word1):
    word2 = word2.replace(char, '')
```

Comment: if word1 = 'heli' and word2 = 'jello', i only want it to replace one 'l' from 'jello', what do I do.

Comment: You can pass `1` as the third parameter to `str.replace` to restrict it to only replacing it *once*. It will pick the first match.

Answer (score 0):

The `del` keyword does not do what you are thinking it does in python. To delete from a string, try something like

```
i = 5
word = 'abcdefghijk'
#delete the i'th element
word = word[0:i] + word [i+1:]
```

There is rarely a good reason to use the `del` keyword in python

Answer (score 0):

your del line uses incorrect syntax. del cannot be used on characters in a string. Assuming word1 and word2 are strings.. you can't just delete a letter from a string. However, you can use str.replace():

```
for c word1:
    if c in word2:
        word2 = word2.replace(c, '')
```

You must create a new string to do this, as simply doing `word2.replace(c, '')` won't actually modify word2.

Hence the `word2 =` bit

Answer (score 0):

The [*str.translate*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method is very well suited to this task.  If you pass *None* as the first argument, the second argument lists all the characters to be removed:

```
>>> 'clementine'.translate(None, 'welcome')
'ntin'
>>> 'apple'.translate(None, 'orange')
'ppl'
```

**Q.**  Variant of the question: `if word1 = 'heli' and word2 = 'jello', i only want it to replace one 'l' from 'jello', what do I do.`

**A.** Use [*str.find*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and [string slicing](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) to isolate and remove one character at a time (don't use *str.replace* which does a multi-replace):

```
>>> word1 = 'heli'
>>> word2 = 'jello'
>>> for c in word1:
        i = word2.find(c)
        if i != -1:
            word2 = word2[:i] + word2[i+1:]

>>> word2
'jlo'
```